# unable to view on multiple devices - Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to preview my UI on multiple devices on Xcode 14, in previous versions I was able to do that using (cmd + alt + return) or I could add preview provider, but since I update the key shortcut are not working also the preview button disappeared. here is the view controller code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var TestLBEL: UILabel!
}
```

I was searching and trying but it's not working for me, I will appreciate any help. thank you

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you intended to create a SwiftUI project; that is where the previews and [preview providers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previewprovider) are, and that is where your Command-Option-Return shows or hides the preview.

You've created a UIKit (storyboard) project, and UIKit doesn't do that. Start over, and this time pick SwiftUI.

[image]

Comment: can i ask please how to create SwiftUI project rather than UIkit?

Comment: When you start creating the project, after you've said what architecture you want, there is a screen that asks you, among other things (like the name of the project), which kind you want. Pick SwiftUI.